# Flex 4 > spark.components.VideoPlayer > How to switch bit rate?

Tags: flex4, components, audiovideoplayback, videodisplay

The VideoPlayer (possibly VideoDisplay also) component is capable of somehow automatically picking the best quality video on the list it's given. An example is here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/mediaClasses/DynamicStreamingVideoItem.html#includeExamplesSummary

I cannot find the answers to below questions.

Assuming that the server that streams recorded videos is capable of switching across same videos with different bit rates and streaming them from any point within their timelines:

1. Is the bandwidth test/calculation within this component only done before the video starts playing, at which point it picks the best video source and never uses the other ones? Or, does it continuously or periodically execute its bandwidth tests and does it accordingly switch between video sources during the playback?
2. Does it support setting the video source through code and can its automatic switching between video sources be turned off (in case I want to provide this functionality to the user in the form of some button/dropdown or similar)? I know that the preferred video source can be set, but this only means that that video source will be tested/attempted first.
3. What other media servers can be used with this component, besides the one provided by Adobe, to achieve automated and manual switching between different quality of same video?

---

Obviously, I'd like to create a player that is smart enough to automatically switch between different quality of videos, and that will support manual instructions related to which source to play - both without interrupting the playback, or at least without restarting it (minor interruptions acceptable). Also, the playback needs to be able to start at any given point within the video, after enough data has been buffered (of course), but most importantly, I want to be able to start the playback beyond what's buffered. A note or two about fast-forwarding is not going to hurt, if anyone knows anything.

Thank you for your time.